# eclipse-how to add existing source folder from remote network drive

Tags: java, eclipse, network-drive

I have mapped a remove drive onto my W: on Computer on my PC.
From that drive I have linked a source folder onto my eclipse using

File>New>Java Project >link additional source and put in `W:\remotefolder\removtesrc` named as `src`

It all works except when I put my PC to sleep for the night and try to work it again next morning.
Those linked source all disappeared from my eclipse project.

When I try to see if I needed to link them again by go into project>properties>Java Build Path. 
I see that my linked source folder still there

```
project/src - W:\remotefolder\removtesrc
```

So I can not re-add existing source folder...
But they are not showing up in my project so I can not work on them...
I tried Refresh the project and it didn't work

So what is the easiest to make them come back to me again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close eclipse before shutting down, restart eclipse after resume. No, really - Windows disconnects remote drives during sleep: network adapter is suspended, thus disconnecting from the network, thus no more remote drives. During resume, the network stack takes more time to resume than the remote drive stack, thus no more remote drive.

I think you can mark the remote drive to be available when offline (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/working-with-network-files-when-you-are-offline), but I've never used this feature of Windows.

Comment: yes you are correct I just did a eclipse restart after everything else failed and it worked for me.